# Deno.run not working with --allow-net flag

Tags: typescript, ffmpeg, deno

I'm trying to use `Deno.run` to execute an `ffmpeg` subprocess, followed the deno doc here ([https://doc.deno.land/https/github.com/denoland/deno/releases/latest/download/lib.deno.d.ts#Deno.run](https://doc.deno.land/https/github.com/denoland/deno/releases/latest/download/lib.deno.d.ts#Deno.RunOptions))

```
const ffmpeg = Deno.run({ cmd: ['--allow-run', '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg', '-i','-',

   // video codec config: low latency, adaptive bitrate
   '-c:v', 'libx264', '-preset', 'veryfast', '-tune', 'zerolatency',

   // audio codec config: sampling frequency (11025, 22050, 44100), bitrate 64 kbits
   '-c:a', 'aac', '-ar', '44100', '-b:a', '64k',

   //force to overwrite
   '-y',

   // used for audio sync
   '-use_wallclock_as_timestamps', '1',
   '-async', '1',

   //'-filter_complex', 'aresample=44100', // resample audio to 44100Hz, needed if input is not 44100
   //'-strict', 'experimental',
   '-bufsize', '1000',
   '-f', 'flv', 
   // allow run flag
  rtmpUrl]
 });
```

And I get the following error. I'm passing the `--allow-run` flag as the first argument, is there something that I'm missing here?

```
error: Uncaught PermissionDenied: access to run a subprocess, run again with the --allow-run flag
```

Comment: can you post the full run command?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently while running the script itself it accepts the flags, so `deno run --allow-net --allow-run server.ts` works and does not throw me an error. I was passing it inside as a `cmd`.